# How to know which fix has been done in which branch with TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

We are using TFS with a branch per release strategy.
Production's fix are usually done in the release branch then merge back into the Main branch. But sometimes the bug is too important to be done in the Release branch so it's done in the Main branch and delivered with the next version.
A fix is registered in TFS as a bug work item.

How can I know which fix that has been done in the Main branch but not in the Release Branch ?
Can I use the same method to know which Feature will be released with the next version ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Link of **VersionedItem type** to the bug Work Item using the server path to the branch .
[image]

There's also a "Found in Build" field for that. Through the build, you can also know which code it built, which work items , which changesets.
[image]

Another way is to use the tag, using some convention such as "Branch=Name".

To know which feature will be released with the next version, the simplest way is to compare both version.

Comment: If I commit a fix associated with a Work Item in the branch Release and run a build.
Then I do the correction on the Main Branch, two weeks later I merge Main on Release, run a new Build. Will the Work Item be associated with this new build ? If not, it's perfect !^^

Comment: What' your mean of associated  with this new build. You have committed a fix.  It seems you didn't change the build definition. However, if you got an error during the new build, it will create a new workitem.

Comment: For me, a work item associated to a build is a work item that appears in the section "Associated work items" of a build summary : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/807609